# Transfer value of one JLabel to another

Tags: java, calculator

I have this calculator working, but I can't figure out how to get the value in the resultpane to the first textbox when you click the "finish" button.

I'm new to Java. I've tried doing it, but I kept getting an error. i put the errors in the code with //

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import static javax.swing.Action.NAME;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TestCalculator {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new TestCalculator();
}

public TestCalculator() {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            }

            ResultPane resultPane = new ResultPane();

            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
            frame.setGlassPane(resultPane);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            frame.add(new CalculatorPane(resultPane));
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);

        }
    });
}

public class ResultPane extends JPanel {

    private JLabel result;
    private Timer timer;

    private int xDelta = (Math.random() > 0.5) ? 1 : -1;
    private int yDelta = (Math.random() > 0.5) ? 1 : -1;

    ;

    public ResultPane() {
        setOpaque(false);
        setLayout(null);
        result = new JLabel();
        Font font = result.getFont();
        font = font.deriveFont(Font.BOLD, 26f);
        result.setFont(font);
        add(result);
        timer = new Timer(40, new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Point point = result.getLocation();
                point.x += xDelta;
                point.y += yDelta;
                if (point.x < 0) {
                    point.x = 0;
                    xDelta *= -1;
                } else if (point.x + result.getWidth() > getWidth()) {
                    point.x = getWidth() - result.getWidth();
                    xDelta *= -1;
                }
                if (point.y < 0) {
                    point.y = 0;
                    yDelta *= -1;
                } else if (point.y + result.getHeight() > getHeight()) {
                    point.y = getHeight() - result.getHeight();
                    yDelta *= -1;
                }
                result.setLocation(point);
                repaint();
            }

        });
        timer.start();
    }

    public void setResult(Number number) {
        result.setText("Result: " + NumberFormat.getNumberInstance().format(number));
        result.setSize(result.getPreferredSize());
        setVisible(true);
    }

}

public class CalculatorPane extends JPanel {

    private final ResultPane resultPane;

    private final JLabel firstNumberLabel = new JLabel("First Number:");
    private final JLabel secondNumberLabel = new JLabel("Second Number:");

    private final JTextField firstNumberField = new JTextField(5);
    private final JTextField secondNumberField = new JTextField(5);

    public double result = 0.0;

    public CalculatorPane(ResultPane resultPane) {

        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;

        this.resultPane = resultPane;

        JPanel fields = new JPanel();
        fields.add(firstNumberLabel);
        fields.add(firstNumberField);
        fields.add(secondNumberLabel);
        fields.add(secondNumberField);

        add(fields, gbc);

        JPanel buttons = new JPanel();
        buttons.add(new JButton(new AddAction()));
        buttons.add(new JButton(new SubtractAction()));
        buttons.add(new JButton(new MultiplyAction()));
        buttons.add(new JButton(new DivideAction()));
        buttons.add(new JButton(new ToText1Action()));

        add(buttons, gbc);

    }

    public class AddAction extends AbstractAction {

        public AddAction() {
            putValue(NAME, "+");
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try {
                double num1 = Double.parseDouble(firstNumberField.getText());
                double num2 = Double.parseDouble(secondNumberField.getText());

                double result = num1 + num2;

                //num1.setResult(firstNumberField);
                resultPane.setResult(result);
            } catch (NumberFormatException exp) {
            }
        }

    }
    public class SubtractAction extends AbstractAction {

        public SubtractAction() {
            putValue(NAME, "-");
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try {
                double num1 = Double.parseDouble(firstNumberField.getText());
                double num2 = Double.parseDouble(secondNumberField.getText());

                double result = num1 - num2;
                resultPane.setResult(result);
            } catch (NumberFormatException exp) {
            }
        }

    }
    public class MultiplyAction extends AbstractAction {

        public MultiplyAction() {
            putValue(NAME, "x");
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try {
                double num1 = Double.parseDouble(firstNumberField.getText());
                double num2 = Double.parseDouble(secondNumberField.getText());

                double result = num1 * num2;
                resultPane.setResult(result);
            } catch (NumberFormatException exp) {
            }
        }

    }
    public class DivideAction extends AbstractAction {

        public DivideAction() {
            putValue(NAME, "/");
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try {
                double num1 = Double.parseDouble(firstNumberField.getText());
                double num2 = Double.parseDouble(secondNumberField.getText());

                double result = num1 / num2;
                resultPane.setResult(result);
            } catch (NumberFormatException exp) {
            }
        }

    }
    public class ToText1Action extends AbstractAction {
        public ToText1Action() {
            putValue(NAME, "Finish");

        }
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String resultText = resultPane.getResultText(); // = resultPane.getResultText();
                                                            //             ^ error cannot find symbol
            firstNumberField.setText(resultText);
        }
    }
    public String getResultText() {
        result.getText(); //result.getText();
    }                     //      ^ error: double cannot be dereferenced
}   
}
```

Comment: Again?  What was wrong the other 3 answers to the [exact same last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23713392/how-to-transfer-a-value-from-one-jlabel-to-another)?  And the answer you've selected is the same answer given by @HovercraftFullOfEels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't the best way to do it but you can do

```
 public String getResultText(){
     return ""+result;
 }
```

You don't need to do getText() or toString() (i think not exists, is primitive type), but you have to add "". Java do the casting alone.

Add new code and overwrite:

```
public class ResultPane extends JPanel {

private JLabel result;
private Timer timer;

private int xDelta = (Math.random() > 0.5) ? 1 : -1;
private int yDelta = (Math.random() > 0.5) ? 1 : -1;

public ResultPane() {
    setOpaque(false);
    setLayout(null);
    result = new JLabel();
    Font font = result.getFont();
    font = font.deriveFont(Font.BOLD, 26f);
    result.setFont(font);
    add(result);
    timer = new Timer(40, new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Point point = result.getLocation();
            point.x += xDelta;
            point.y += yDelta;
            if (point.x < 0) {
                point.x = 0;
                xDelta *= -1;
            } else if (point.x + result.getWidth() > getWidth()) {
                point.x = getWidth() - result.getWidth();
                xDelta *= -1;
            }
            if (point.y < 0) {
                point.y = 0;
                yDelta *= -1;
            } else if (point.y + result.getHeight() > getHeight()) {
                point.y = getHeight() - result.getHeight();
                yDelta *= -1;
            }
            result.setLocation(point);
            repaint();
        }

    });
    timer.start();
}

public void setResult(Number number) {
    result.setText("Result: " + NumberFormat.getNumberInstance().format(number));
    result.setSize(result.getPreferredSize());
    setVisible(true);
}

public String getResultText(){
    return result.getText();
}

}
```

Comment: String resultText = resultPane.getResultText();  is still getting an error

Comment: Because resultPane doesn't have method called getResultText(), look about the brackets and level in your code. Now getResultText() is in calculatorpane class

Comment: I have to say you one think, I don't think this is the best way to do a calculator. You don't need all these panes.

Comment: Im very new to java so i dont know how to get resultPane the method

Comment: Don't use EventQueue. Use SwingWorker. You must put the method in resultPane class.

Comment: i put the method into the class but is still giving me the cannot find symbol error

Comment: Ok forget all the previous comments. Get my code and read it and overwrite in yours. Then delete getResultText() from the other class

Comment: It works but brings "Result: " with it too. Any fix for that?

Comment: OK: delete "Result:"+ in setResult method.

Comment: Google for examples of use Swing controls. It's good to begin with heritage and other things but you can do this without actions. In addition, you must think in do several classes, because it's difficult to read this in one file. KIS (Keep it simple). PD: when i put SWINGWORKER i want to say SWINGUTILITIES class, sorry, mindblowing!

Comment: This is solution tightly couples the various components which would make it difficult to expand in the future which would be better served through the use of some kind of model/observer pattern as demonstrated in one of the [answers presented to the duplicate of this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23713392/how-to-transfer-a-value-from-one-jlabel-to-another/23718319#23718319) which would indicate that the OP is simply after a copy-n-paste solution and not truley interested in learning to solve there own problems...